# Is there a way to save a JavaScript object to a JSON file and can I choose the directory in which it is saved in?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I want to know How do I save a JavaScript object to a JSON file that I can name and choose the directory where it is saved.

I get data from a form then I use that data to create a JavaScript object, I then save it in the variable jsonClientEnregistre.

How can I use jsonClientEnregistre to create a JSON file containing the object in JSON format?

```
myApp.controller('adminCtrl',function($scope, $http, $location){

$scope.submit = function() {

  var clientEnregistre = {
     numClient: parseInt($scope.numClient),
     rue: $scope.rue,
     numRue: parseInt($scope.numRue),
     codePostal: parseInt($scope.codePostal),
     localite: $scope.localite
    };
    var jsonClientEnregistre = JSON.stringify(clientEnregistre);
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot create files in your browser.

Comment: You can save things to local storage, but you cannot access the client filesystem directly.

Comment: oh I see, so i cant create a new file but i can access and write on an existing one @Pointy ?

Comment: Google "MDN local storage", it's a way to store strings that are associated with your website domain, and you can recall them later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.showSaveFilePicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker) to prompt the user to save the file.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Bob',
  toys: ['Car', 'Train'],
  age: 4
}

const save = async () => {
  const handle = await showSaveFilePicker()
  const writer = await handle.createWritable()
  await writer.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
  await writer.close()
}
```

Here is a link to the repl: https://replit.com/@Programmerraj/show-save-file-picker#script.js.

You have to open it in a new tab for the repl to work: https://show-save-file-picker.programmerraj.repl.co/.